# Why do Mat types not need to be pointers?

Tags: opencv, pointers, mat

beginner in openCV and i'm just wondering why it is that Mat data types do not require pointer initiation. You can use

```
Mat image
```

instead of

```
Mat* image
```

Answer (score 2):

The first allocates the space for a Mat object (the header if you like) in exactly the same way as `int a` allocates space for an int.

When you specify the size and type of the data, or load an image into it, it will allocate the memory for the actual data.

This is really an elementary C or C++ programming question, nothing to do with openCV. The `Mat img` and Mat *img =new(Mat(...))` both make space for the Mat itself (just the header). In either case you can also specify the size of the data and the Mat will internally allocate memory for the image data. This is invisible to you and nothing to do with how you store the Mat.

Comment: so in theory, i could make a Mat* img and later on just *img = Mat(param,param,param,param)?

Comment: no - you can do `Mat* img = new(Mat(rows,cols,type))` assuming you are in c++

Comment: hey man if it isn't worth the bother i would really benefit from an explanation. do you only  need to specify a pointer when you are allocating data? that makes sense. But why is it that 'Mat img(rows,cols,type)' doesn't need a pointer?